# Temp file fails verification every time I try to update MiKTeX

Tags: errors, installing, miktex, updating

I have been using TeX for two years now, mostly as a replacement for Word. I'm an academic and I like the typesetting capability, especially when I need to use math, but am not an advanced user. I attempted to update my distribution recently because I was able to glean from other questions on this site that doing this would likely solve another problem I had. When the update failed, I looked for solutions here and found none, so I uninstalled and reinstalled MiKTeX (using Protext). Then I ran into the same problem again when trying to update the distribution. I tried several different mirrors (med.harvard, bay.chicago, and most recently mackichan) and got a similar error each time. My system is a Vista 64-bit. The log file is pasted below:

```
MiKTeX Update Wizard Report

Version: 2.9.4497
Date: Tuesday, May 21, 2013
Time: 13:01:19
starting package maintenance...

installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"

package repository: http://ctan.mackichan.com/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/

lightweight database digest: c037a7e4ea61280289db1153192ca40a

going to download 10661531 bytes

going to install 10 file(s) (1 package(s))

going to remove 44 file(s) (2 package(s))

downloading h ttp://ctan.mackichan.com/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...

10661531 bytes, 483.70 KB/Sec

visiting repository h ttp://ctan.mackichan.com/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...

repository type: remote package repository

loading lightweight database...

downloading h ttp://ctan.mackichan.com/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...

132563 bytes, 322.83 KB/Sec

lightweight database digest: c037a7e4ea61280289db1153192ca40a


Error: The operation could not be completed because the following file failed verification:



C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\mik8748.tmp
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of this site.