# mpm manual installation, file failed verification

Tags: packages, miktex

I am trying to install packages manually from a local folder with MikTeX. I have a folder with files downloaded from [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages) like:

```
folder/
  biblatex.zip
  pgfplots.tar.lzma
  acronym.tar.lzma
  ...
```

And I install packages using the command line, e.g.:

```
mpm --install acronym
```

It works for most packages but not for `biblatex` and `pgfplots`, the log file tell me that:

```
2016-02-03 08:29:07,206+0100 INFO  mpmcli - starting: mpmcli 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2016-02-03 08:29:07,206+0100 INFO  mpmcli - starting package maintenance...
2016-02-03 08:29:07,206+0100 INFO  mpmcli - installation directory: "****\MiKTeX 2.9"
2016-02-03 08:29:07,206+0100 INFO  mpmcli - package repository: "****\packages"
2016-02-03 08:29:07,424+0100 INFO  mpmcli - lightweight database digest: b23bd77b3f11400395e77f07730e1abf
2016-02-03 08:29:07,424+0100 INFO  mpmcli - going to install 112 file(s) (1 package(s))
2016-02-03 08:29:07,471+0100 INFO  mpmcli - visiting repository "****\packages"...
2016-02-03 08:29:07,471+0100 INFO  mpmcli - repository type: local package repository
2016-02-03 08:29:07,471+0100 INFO  mpmcli - loading lightweight database...
2016-02-03 08:29:07,674+0100 INFO  mpmcli - lightweight database digest: b23bd77b3f11400395e77f07730e1abf
2016-02-03 08:29:07,736+0100 FATAL mpmcli - The operation could not be completed because the following file failed verification:  ****\packages\pgfplots.tar.lzma
2016-02-03 08:29:07,736+0100 FATAL mpmcli - Info: 
2016-02-03 08:29:07,736+0100 FATAL mpmcli - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\PackageInstaller.cpp
2016-02-03 08:29:07,736+0100 FATAL mpmcli - Line: 3291
```

I found some posts with the same error but none of these helped me:

- [Temp file fails verification every time I try to update MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115421/temp-file-fails-verification-every-time-i-try-to-update-miktex)
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256258/need-help-for-failed-verification-error-when-install-miktex-2-9-through-net-in?bcsi-ac-95bb4efa6a1646c8=24CAB8E000000303WtjD040us9/v3aM/r4dSi+O/X2MNEQAAAwMAACVhSgEIBwAAAAAAACNYRgA=

I checked that there were no MikTeX executable running (`latex`, `pdflatex`, ...) when I was installing the package.

Why do some packages work while others don't?

Comment: Perhaps the download was faulty, or the information in the database files (the miktex-zz-...files) doesn't fit. Or there is a fault in the package  in which case you should make a bug report.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried downloading multiple times, and also for various sources in various formats (`.tar.lzma`, `.zip`, ...) but I get the same error each time. I will test packages on another installation and check if they work before making a bug report.